# Antipatterns, refactoring C# code sample

Tags: c#, refactoring, anti-patterns

I wrote code, but it does not look very elegant and intuitive. I try to refactor it now. Do you see any antipatterns in my code?

I am working with images. I got images from folder, process it and delete after this.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to exit");
 bool isEmptyFolderFlagSet = false;
 while (true)
 {
     if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
     {
         appExited(null, EventArgs.Empty);
         return;
     }    
     List<string> images = new List<string>(System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat
         (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.pdf"), System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.tif")));
     if (images.Count == 0 && !isEmptyFolderFlagSet)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Waiting for image...");
         isEmptyFolderFlagSet = true;
     }
     else
     {
         isEmptyFolderFlagSet = false;
         foreach (string imagePath in images)
         {
             try
             {
                 processing.ProcessingFile(imagePath);
                 System.IO.File.Delete(imagePath);
             }
             catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
             }
         }
     }
     Thread.Sleep(500);
 }
```

Comment: This is a polling loop. So instead of Thread.Sleep I would use a timer and define a callback.

Comment: Belongs at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Place a condition in 'while' clause

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to exit");
   while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))
   {      
      //Code here
   }
   ```
2. If there are a lot of files? you should use EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles (will be much faster)
3. Instead of costly try..catch that catch only FileNotFound you can use System.IO.File.Exits(filename) method.
4. As mentioned before, Timer with callback function (may be anonymous) will be more appropriate.